# Can i use Ubuntu 14.04 32bit on 4GB ram?

Tags: 14.04, ram, 32-bit

like the title,

if yes it can use all my RAM if needed ? or max just 2GB

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Short answer: YES.**

The limit of 32bit is exactly 4Gb. In case of Ubuntu even a bigger amount of ram can be used with 32bit if you are running a so-called 'PAE' kernel. The installer is smart enough to choose for you the best kernel based on the ram amount.

Comment: Actually there is *only* a pae kernel these days.

Comment: psusi, I didn't noticed that. :) Thanks for info.

Answer (score 2):

32-bit processors can access 4GB of RAM maximum without PAE (physical address extension). With PAE, it can access 64GB of RAM.